# Не срабатывает z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

Есть два блока `.name-block` и `.review-block`. Второй должен слегка наслаиваться на первый, я это реализовал при помощи отрицательного `margin-top`, но ничего не получилось. `.name-block` "выше" чем `.review-block`, а должно быть наоборот.

```
                        <div class="review-left">
                        <div class="name-block">
                            <img src="img/avatar-1.png" alt="" class="avatar">
                            <div class="text">
                                <p class="username">Lorem ipsum.</p>
                                <p class="who-is">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="review-block">
                            <p class="review-cont">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, tempora.</p>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
```

и стили:

```
.name-block
        position: relative
        width: 488px
        height: 144px
        background-color: #082846
        opacity: .99
        z-index: 1

.review-block
        width: 591px
        margin-left: 50px
        margin-top: -10px
        z-index: 10
```

Comment: Возможно для review-block стоит задать свойство position?

Comment: ему тоже добавлял position: relative - не помогло

Answer (score 3, accepted):

z-index тут вообще не при чём: второй блок и так будет наслаиваться на первый, потому что он идёт вторым в потоке. Просто надо обоим блокам задать position: relative, и второй блок с помощью отрицательного top наложить на первый:

```css
.name-block {
        position: relative;
        width: 488px;
        height: 144px;
        background-color: #082846;
        opacity: .99;
       }

.review-block {
        position: relative;
        width: 591px;
        height: 100px;
        margin-left: 50px;
        top: -30px;
        background-color: red;
       }
```

```html
<div class="review-left">
                        <div class="name-block">
                            <img src="img/avatar-1.png" alt="" class="avatar">
                            <div class="text">
                                <p class="username">Lorem ipsum.</p>
                                <p class="who-is">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="review-block">
                            <p class="review-cont">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, tempora.</p>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
```

Comment: я уже присваивал обоим блокам position:relative - не помогло

Comment: @nirolo1, ну ты же видишь мой пример? Что именно тебе не помогло?

Comment: присвоил обоим relative и второму блоку отрицательный top. И по прежнему первый блок выше второго

Comment: @nirolo1, мой пример ты видишь?!? :))) нажми кнопку "выполнить код" и посмотри - это то, что тебе надо?

Comment: Да, то что нужно. но у меня наоборот первый блок наслаивается на второй.

Comment: @nirolo1, ну так значит просто возьми мой код и не парься :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72016/discussion-between-nirolo1-and-humster-spb).